# Convert DataTable field from String to double

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to retrieve data from my SQL base to a `DataTable` and make some decimal operations on some fields.

Since I can get `string`s, `int`s and `double`s in my `DataTable` is initialize like this `new DataTable();`. <s>So the default type is set to `string`</s> ***update:*** This is wrong, it is `decimal`. So no need to convert.

Imagine I want to sum a field from my `DataTable`

```
myRow = 2;
double sum = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    if (row.Field<String>(myRow) != "")
        sum = sum + double.Parse(row.Field<String>(myRow), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
}
```

I prevent empty fields to be added. So I don't try to convert an empty string.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'.

If there is no "good" way to convert this, I can change my `DataTable` to get only `decimals`, but how do i `Fill` with `Decimal`s?

***Update***
Since the default type is `decimal`, I can do

```
sum = sum + (double) row.Field<decimal>(myRow);
```

One work around would be making my database do the sum.

Comment: In datatable the field is `'System.Decimal'`, you are trying to cast the same to string

Comment: Question unclear. This indicates it's stored as string: `row.Field<String>`. But the error indicates it's stored as decimal. Then you dont need to parse a string to decimal if it's already one.

Comment: _"Or I could do a SQL request to do my sum"_ Uhm, of course you could do that. But what is your question now?

Comment: Default type is `Decimal` in `DataTable`? I thought it was `String`

Comment: Fixing the data type. I'll edit that.

Comment: The follow is getting a column, ow a row : row.Field<String>(myRow).  Should be row.Field<String>("column name")

Answer (score 1):

```
if(row.Field<String>(myRow) != ""){
    var stringToDouble = Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<String>(myRow)); 
    //Or you can do Convert.ToDecimal(row.Field<String>(myRow));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like the `Convert.ToDouble()` methodology as it does not allow to set the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` for comma or dot decimal separator, instead one practical way to solve this is using:

```
double result = 0;
double.TryParse(<DataTableObjectField>.ToString(), out result);
```

In case the cell/field is empty, the `.TryParse(..)` will return False, hence leave the `result` equal to zero.